# Is there a difference between nested and non nested else/else ifs?

Tags: c#, vb.net, if-statement

I have a task at work to rewrite old vb code into c# and i came across this

```vb
If (termNumber = TermNumberCode.FallWinter) Then
    Dim first_term As String = " ((Course.dbo.CourseList.[Year])=@TermYear) AND ((Course.dbo.CourseList.TermNumber)=3)  "

    Dim second_term As String = " ((Course.dbo.CourseList.Year)=@TermYear+1) AND ((Course.dbo.CourseList.TermNumber)=1)  "
    query &= "  AND ( ( " & first_term & " ) OR ( " & second_term & " ) )  "

Else
    If (termNumber = TermNumberCode.Summer) Then
        query &= " AND ((Course.dbo.CourseList.[Year])=@TermYear) AND ((Course.dbo.CourseList.TermNumber)=2)  "

    ElseIf (termNumber = TermNumberCode.Fall) Then
        query &= " AND ((Course.dbo.CourseList.[Year])=@TermYear) AND ((Course.dbo.CourseList.TermNumber)=3)  "

    ElseIf (termNumber = TermNumberCode.Winter) Then
        query &= " AND ((Course.dbo.CourseList.[Year])=@TermYear) AND ((Course.dbo.CourseList.TermNumber)=1)  "

    End If
End If
```

I was wondering, Is this the same as writing it like this or if there is any special significance or nesting the ifs like that?

```vb
If (termNumber = TermNumberCode.FallWinter) Then
    code...

Else if (termNumber = TermNumberCode.Summer)
    code...

Else If (termNumber = TermNumberCode.Fall) 
    code...

Else //(termNumber = TermNumberCode.Winter)
    code...
```

Comment: Have you thought about moving to a `Select Case`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form

```
if #1..    
else
   if #2..
   else if #3..
   else ..
end
```

is equivalent to

```
if #1..
else if #2..
else if #3..
else ..
```

That is, the immediate nesting inside an `else` does not affect the logic of the nested branches. This can be repeated indefinitely - although the non-nested form is arguably more clear here.

*However,* in the presented code the `else` and a final `else if` is transposed, which won't make a difference *if* termNumber if constrained to the set checked against. But it *is* a difference - what if termNumber is `TermNumberCode.SpringBreak`? - and thus it must be considered separately from the transformation above..

Comment: Thanks, this made a lot of sense.

Comment: @173901 Cool :) Good job on using parameters with a "dynamic query"! Many programmers will embed the values directly into the SQL string .. yech! You could continue this separation to make the dynamic query simpler as well - e.g. for the single terms, just need to bind to termNumber.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have any code outside of the inner `If/End If` they are effectively equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

They are functionally identical.

Comment: just because this post is likely to get flagged as low-quality, can you elaborate on what you mean.  Four word answers are usually better left as comments.

Comment: @KyleMit It is an answer to the question.  It is complete.  There is nothing else to really explain; doing so would simply be noise.  The other two answers simply say this, and then go on to talk about stuff that is not at all in the question, only obscuring the actual answer.  Some questions just have simple answers.

Comment: Fair enough.  It came up in the review queue and at first glance it looked like it could use extra info.  If I'm wearing OP's shoes, it just wouldn't convince me of anything.  Does OP know what it means for something to be 'functionally identical'? Asserting this *does* answer the question, but I'd still be left having no clue *why*.

Comment: @KyleMit A formal proof would be very hard, long, unlikely to be understood by any reader, and generally not helpful.  What else would you expect it to say?  Given the OP's understanding of the code, he is clearly reasonably sure that they're the same.  The common cases can all be clearly shown to be functionally identical.  It just comes down to whether there is some obscure edge case in which it would matter.  There isn't.  Proving that would be...hard.

Answer (score 1):

This equivalence is easier to see in the C-style languages.  In those languages there is no "else if" keyword - that's just a formatted combination of "else" and "if".  In other words, as long as you have "if" and "else" in a language where white space is unimportant, you always get "else if".

In VB however, there is an "ElseIf" keyword and you have all those "End If" statements, so it's not just a white space rearrangement.  But you still have the underlying equivalence between "Else 
 If" and "ElseIf".

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET has two styles of syntax for if and else.  The first style has the first statement to be controlled immediately follow `Then` or `Else`, without an intervening colon or line end.  The effect of the conditional will extend to the end of the line.  Use of `End If` is not allowed with this style.

The second style has a line end or colon immediately follow a `Then` or `Else`.  In this style, the condition will affect everything until the next `Else`, `ElseIf`, or `End If`.  Note that line-ends are not significant in this style; one may include multiple `Then`, `Else`, `ElseIf`, and `End If` statements on a single line.

To avoid parsing confusion, certain combinations of styles are forbidden.  In particular, no `If`, `Then`, `ElseIf`, or `Else` of the second style may be controlled by an `If` of the first style, and any `Else` must use the same style as its matching `Then`.  The `ElseIf` keyword is designed to get around these restrictions, since it is regarded as part of a second-style `If`/`Then` construct, rather than being a first-style `Else`.  Note that one could write `Else : If ... Then` using a second-style construct, but separate `End If` statements would be required for the `Then` and the `Else`.  Additionally, note that if one is using the first if/then style and includes an `If` as the first statement of the `Else`, a space between the `Else` and `If` is required.